# 500 internal server error with RewriteRule php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s()]+)/?$ product.php?group=$1&salt=$2&name=$3 [L]
```

It was working fine with my previous hosting but when i change my hosting to 1and1 (Linux) its gives me 500 internal server error.
Please help me whats going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure that your new provider has `mod_rewrite` enabled? Its the most common reason for seeing 500 errors with `mod_rewrite`.

To make a quick test just replace your complete `.htaccess` with the following lines (**make a backup of your original `.htaccess` first**)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.google.com [R]
```

If `mod_rewrite` is enabled it will redirect all your requests to Google.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to install mod rewrite would be to use `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-\s()]+)/?$ product.php?group=$1&salt=$2&name=$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This will ensure the mod rewrite is only run if mod_rewrite is installed. This should at least stop the server error. If it doesn't this means you've got a syntax error with your rewrite rule.